# Calculate Bezier curve and draw

Tags: c++

I want to Calculate Bezier Curve which should return me x,y where I can plug and draw the line. I have to use this formula

[image]

where t is in [0,1]

```c
   struct myPoint {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

void drawBezier(myPoint p0, myPoint p1, myPoint p2, myPoint p3) {
    myPoint result;
    
    for(double t = 0.0; t<=1.0; t+=0.001){
        result = pow((1-t),3) * p0 + 3 * pow((1-t),2) * t * p1 + 3 * (1-t) * pow(t,2) * p2 + pow(t,3) * p3;
    }
    
}
```

How can I actually receive x,y out of this? I am not sure how to calculate this correctly. Can someone give me advice

Comment: Do you have appropriate operator overloads for `myPoint`?

Comment: Are you asking how to return something from a function? That's a case for a C++ tutorial rather. Also, note that your code does not make much sense: Inside the loop, you assign to the same object over and over. Also, none of what is inside causes side effects or gives you any result to work with...

Comment: I know how to return something from a function. I do not know how to properly plug data into this formula to get x,y out of it and be able to push it in my function which draws a line

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you don't need to return anything, since the loop will give you a result for each iteration, so you can draw the result after each iteration directly.

In case you need to return something from the function, you need to make the loop outside the function itself.

Comment: With the code I am getting bunch of errors `Invalid operands to binary expression`. How can I get the x,y out of this math formula? I think now it calculates only one value

Comment: Like there says `p0`, how do I know if there should be p0.x or y?